# "pip install mysql-python" ведёт к ошибке: error: command 'cl.exe' failed: No such file or director

Tags: mysql, python, windows, установка, pip

Пытаюсь установить mysql-python

```
C:\Users\Одиночка>pip install mysql-python
Collecting mysql-python
Using cached MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
Installing collected packages: mysql-python
Running setup.py install for mysql-python ... error
Complete output from command c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\2871~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-cawqiw\\mysql-python\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\2871~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-wuojsd-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win32-2.7
copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7
creating build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb
creating build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
running build_ext
building '_mysql' extension
creating build\temp.win32-2.7
creating build\temp.win32-2.7\Release
cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include" -Ic:\python27\include -Ic:\python27\PC /Tc_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.7\Release\_mysql.obj /Zl
error: command 'cl.exe' failed: No such file or director
```

Установил Visual Studio 2008 2010 2015 
файл cl.exe лежит по пути

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\cl.exe
```

пробовал из под консоли Studio запустить, получаю такое..

```
error: command 'C:\\Users\\\xce\xe4\xe8\xed\xee\xf7\xea\xe0\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

В общем суть я думаю ясна вам, подскажите как быть.... проект стоит из за этой фигни

Comment: Что выдает вот такая команда: cl.exe ?

Comment: Не стоит несколько версий VS ставить без разбору. Конкретную ошибку можно попробовать с помощью [SetEnv починить](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32740319/4279), но если подобные ошибки вас останавливают, то вам вероятно не стоит пытаться компилировать на Windows. Поищите бинарные установщики, [к примеру](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python) или вообще  [на conda перейдите](https://www.continuum.io/downloads)